# Insert respective comma separated values to their respective db fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 comma separated values in input field text box as `answers` and `qid` as input names .

```
answers = abc,def,ghi
qid = 1,2,3
```

How I want to get inserted:

```
qid|answer
--------------
  1|abc
  2|def
  3|ghi
```

But according to the code it is inserting `abc` for all 3 qids similarly
`def` and `ghi` for all 3 qids, in that way I am  getting 9 tuples instead of 3.

Code:

```
 $answers=$this->input->post("answers");
 $question=$this->input->post("qid");

$ans = explode(',',$answers); 
$qid = explode(',',$question); 

foreach($qid as $qids){
    foreach($ans as $anss){
    $data = array(
                'qid' => $qids,
                'user_answer'=>$anss,
            );
        $result = $this->db->insert("user_answer",$data);

    }

}
```

Comment: You need only 1 foreach

Comment: can't you upgrade the frontend that it posts JSON instead off two separated CSV post strings..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only **one** foreach loop

**Note**: This works only if **$ans** and **$qid** records match together(same no of records in both array), otherwise it may misbehave!

```
$answers=$this->input->post("answers");
$question=$this->input->post("qid");

$ans = explode(',',$answers); 
$qid = explode(',',$question); 

foreach($qid as $k => $qids){
    $data = array(
                'qid' => $qids,
                'user_answer'=>$ans[$k],
            );
        $result = $this->db->insert("user_answer",$data);

}
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked like a charm. Please, can you explain the code?

Comment: Simple: Looping on $qid and pass     $qid key ($k) to $ans array.